# Finding optimal k cluster using Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

Is it a good practice to find the optimal k in kmeans clustering in sklearn using inertia (Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center). Assuming, all the other parameters are constant, can i choose k, which has minimum value of inertia ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inertia will always be lower for a higher $k$ (except when the algorithm has gotten stuck at some bad local minimum). So this is not a good technique to choose $k$.

To see this: first, fit with $k$ clusters. Now add a $k+1$st cluster. If you put it really far away from the data, no points would be assigned to it, and the inertia would be the same. If you put it closer to the data, points will be assigned to it *exactly when* it decreases the inertia compared to the $k$-cluster solution. So the best $k+1$-cluster solution is necessarily at least as good in terms of inertia as the best $k$-cluster solution.